# Kotlin generate a map list from properties file

Tags: regex, list, kotlin

I have a properties file with lots of data.

Some data is like this

```
//fruits
banana = '5.5'
apples = '3.6f'
//vegies
carrots = '42.4r'
tomatoes = '3.4.s2'
//There are comments and other text in file
```

and so on

I need to map index/list for each time there is value on the left side of a = sign and get the map/list to the value between the single quotes sign.

Later I want to use the list or map to print its value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val input = """banana = '5.5'
        apples = '3.6f'
        //vegies
        carrots = '42.4r'
        tomatoes = '3.4.s2'"""

    val props = Properties()
    props.load(ByteArrayInputStream(input.toByteArray(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)))
    props.filterValues { it?.toString()?.isNotBlank() ?: false }.toList()
              .forEach { println(it) }
}
```